# Gas flow through pipelines with heat addition

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have data collected from a pipeline 30m long of a forced air flow. As the pipeline is burried to exchange energy with the soil to reduce the air temperature before entering the building (earth-to-air heat exchanger). Therefore I can't assume an adiabatic flow. I found a quite representative model for the input and output temperature and I'm trying to find a model I can use to predict output air velocity considering the losses in system.

In the real model constructed  the pressure loss is expressive, my equivalent length is about 100m so velocity at the end of the pipe is way lower than at the beginning. It's 12.7m/s against 4.97m/s. I'm trying to find which equations I could use to predict this velocity drop. It's been complicated because I can't make the most commons assumptions, as adiabatic flow, constant velocity... I tried Anderson one dimensional flow with heat addition, but it uses the continuity equation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much

Comment: Why is the air velocity lower at the exit than at the entrance?  Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: It was not a exhaust fan, so the velocity measure at the entrance was right bellow the fan with a hot wire anemometer.

Comment: Something is either wrong with your data or your explanation.  If there is no air removed from the 100 m pipe before it exits the end of the pipe, you should get a flow that is close to 12.7 m/s.  As pressure drop occurs in the pipe, air pressure goes down and air velocity goes up.  As air cools in the pipe, the ideal gas law affects air flow, and the flow rate goes down.  These are competing effects, and each effect is a bit difficult to model.

Comment: If there were no heat added, the exit velocity would be higher than the entrance velocity because of the decrease in air density.  This isothermal compressible flow is easy to model.  Adding heat would make the exit velocity even higher.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. In the built system there are 22 bends of 90 degree which could have an air leakage, as I can't say they are completely sealed. So, this could be an explanation for the difference in the velocities. PVC is the material of the pipe.